# Generate multiple or single cell values based on conditions?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

**Problem:**
I have single products and bundled products. I have a single "product ID" column and I want the sheet to recognize both bundled products and single products and, where it is a bundle, to fill the product ID for that bundle.

Here is the layout:

[image: Product layout]

I have a list of bundles and the relevant product information on a separate sheet.

**Explanation:**
In column A, I enter either the product name of the Bundle ID.

**Problem:**
Is it possible for column B to detect whether Column A refers to a Bundle or single product? It detects a bundle, then can it generate the items in for bundle?

For example in A4= " - BUNDLE001" so in column B will generate the relevant product ID: B4= "LG001", B5= "PAN002". But I also need column B to know if it did not Bundle and to display the relevant product ID.

**Sheet Link:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPNYKbtbkaZ2LDrFq2RO_f13cfQeGcWsyhwS5VDkuvk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your A column will look like this:

[image: 0]

then you can use this formula on every row you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(QUERY(Sheet2!A:C, "select C where A = '"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Sheet2!A$2:A))&"'", 0), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), "- (.+)"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: great solution, but how to using that formula without paste on every row? im try using arrayforula on your formula but not working (sry for this dumb question) =ArrayFormula(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(QUERY(Sheet2!A:C, "select C where A = '"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Sheet2!A$2:A))&"'", 0), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()), "- (.+)")))))

Comment: not always (like in your case) is possible to create arrayformula which auto-completes for all rows. also if the picture is the reference then formula is only in B2, B3, B4 and B6

Comment: is there any possible way to make the formula wihtout paste on every row? im try using a help column, that count 1~n but still not find a way

Comment: ummm, yes for the id case i already solved it, but still need a little tweaking, i will post for another question, so thx a lot :)